# How to update 3d tensors with tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensor

I am lost trying to figure out how tow to use `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` for a 3d tensor.

With the working example code, the input data has a shape of `(64,8,768)`
The 1st dimension is the batch size, the second is the channels/patches, and the third is the feature size.

I would like to update the input tensor given indices of the shape `(64,4)`. Notice how only 4 out of the 8 channels/patches are updated for each entry in the batch index.

The features to be used for the update are defined by `updateTensor` which has a shape of `(64,4,768)`

The desired output is the same size as the input `(64,8,768)`

Although after trying with `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`, I get the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__TensorScatterUpdate_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Inner dimensions of output shape must match inner dimensions of updates shape. Output: [64,8,768] updates: [64,4,768] [Op:TensorScatterUpdate]
```

The minimally working code

```
import tensorflow as tf

featureSize = 768
batchSize = 64
patchCount = 8
toUpdatePatchCount = 4

inputTensor = tf.random.normal([batchSize,patchCount,featureSize])
# TensorShape([64, 8, 768])

indices = tf.argsort(
    tf.random.uniform(shape=(batchSize, toUpdatePatchCount)), axis=-1
)
# TensorShape([64, 4])

updateTensor = tf.random.normal([batchSize,toUpdatePatchCount,featureSize])
# TensorShape([64, 4, 768]).shape

tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(inputTensor,indices,updateTensor)
```

Is what I what to achieve doable with `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`?